# When did we begin using metal mesh platforms?

Tags: construction, metallurgy

[image]

I am trying to find the first time we used metal meshes as platforms, like in the image above. I though that a good starting point would be to find the moment metal meshes were created.

Unfortunately, my usual trip to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh for answers did not bring any references or further hints.

Comment: Welcome to History.SE! Are you asking for when a metal mesh was first used or when it was first used as a platform?

Comment: +1 for the trouble of providing an image.

Comment: @ReliableSource: Used as a platform. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Steel [grating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grating) for platform use was first developed and produced by [Walter Irving](http://www.rpi.edu/about/alumni/inductees/irving.html) at the beginning of the 20th century.  It was first used for ventilation of New York's stiflingly hot subway system, but his company, [Irving Subway Grating](http://harscoikg.com/about/index.aspx), quickly marketed it for a range of other uses including [bridge decking](http://www.historylink.org/index.cfm?DisplayPage=output.cfm&file_id=3139) and catwalks.  Aluminum grates (which might be what's shown in the picture) came later.